# MATLAB: Output of a function returns an expression with variables still unevaluated

Tags: matlab

For example, we have the variable TK in our system, which we are plugging into the following:

```
T = input(prompt10);
TK = T + 273.15;

H_SO2_298 = 0.033717;                                  
H_SO2_T = H_SO2_298*exp(-3100*((1/TK)-(1/298.15)))
```

It returns:

```
(151847868636051*exp(62000/5963 - 3100/TK))/4503599627370496
```

We're at a loss. We've been thinking it's an issue with the data class, but trying to modify either the output, the H_SO2_T function, or the original T prompt/TK modification with vpa() doesnt work (or double() for that matter).

Any ideas?

Comment: Since I can't see any symbolic calculation being performed... can you please provide more details about what's going on under the hood?

Comment: Try `clear all` first, or restarting MATLAB, you might have redefined one of these functions. Also, what is `prompt10`?

Comment: seems like `exp` is overloaded.

Comment: Prompt 10 just asks for a numeric input (in degrees Celsius). I’ll provide more context tomorrow!

Answer (score 0):

If I define

```
prompt10 = 'Specify a temperature: '
```

Then your code evaluates to a `double`, like one would expect. You probably have not actually run the code you say. Rather I would guess that at some point, you defined a symbolic variable `Tk`, and then never cleared it. Please try running the following code and seeing if it gives you the result you are seeking. If it gives you the expected result, then that was your problem. Otherwise, we need more details about what `prompt10` is.

```
clear all
prompt10 = 'temperature: ';
T = input(prompt10);
TK = T + 273.15;

H_SO2_298 = 0.033717;                                  
H_SO2_T = H_SO2_298*exp(-3100*((1/TK)-(1/298.15)))
```